# How to prevent double quotes at start and end of DAT file, while writing a pandas DF using to_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My panda DF contains huge data and giving filename with '.DAT' extension (client requirement) and using `to_csv()` to write data.

When I open the file in notepad or any other text viewer, I see double quotes at start and end of the file:

```
" col1|Col2|Col3
  D1|D2|D3
... So On 
  D1n|D2n|D3n "
```

How to remove these double quotes while writing the dataframe as CSV file?

I tried quote, quoting parameters in to_csv, replace function. Please suggest any parameter combination to eliminate this

Comment: Can you provide a minimal text file and source code to reproduce the problem? Looks like your CSV may have some commas or some character which overlaps with delimiter and hence escaped by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To write to a CSV you would do it like this normally.
Generally, this should not give you quotes in the file by default.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path\to\source_folder\input.dat')

df.to_csv('path\to\folder\s.dat')
```

Can we see a sample of the Code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.to_csv("data.dat",header=None, index=None, sep='|', escapechar='')
```